# Azure Active Directory Authentication with Azure Mobile Services Failed

Tags: c#, azure, windows-store-apps, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory

I followed this [Microsoft Azure Mobile Service Authentication Tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users/), to try to add a server authentication function for my Windows Store C# app. However, after completing every step, when I run my app, it showed that the application cannot connect to the service.

I found this useful [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/10/23/troubleshooting-authentication-issues-in-azure-mobile-services.aspx) tallking about troubleshooting Azure Authentication issues in Azure Mobile Service. To troubleshoot, I type the link in the firefox web browser: *myServiceUrl/login/aad*, but I receive the error response:
Authorization has been denied for this request.

I also followed the same tutorial to test with Google Log in. It turns out to work properly. And when I type the link: *myServiceUrl/login/google*, the web browser directed me to the google log in page, unlike the Unauthorization error message when I type in *myServiceUrl/login/aad*.

Although google log in works out fine, but it is desired for us to use Azure Active Directory authentication. Could anyone tell us what could possibly be wrong? Any troubleshooting suggestions are also appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The "Application cannot connect to the service" error comes from whenever the Web Authentication Broker in Windows receives an error response from the resource it is trying to reach. There are a couple of issues that can cause this, and I'll try and address the most common ones.

I noticed the [tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users/) you linked to is for the .NET backend.  If you are using the Mobile Services .NET backend, there is an extra step required to configure the AAD server flow, and it's a common cause of the issue being described. In the tutorial, it's under the title "Configure your .NET mobile service for AAD login." On the backend project, you will need to install the [Mobile Services .NET Backend Security Extension](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Security/) NuGet package. Then, in WebApiConfig.cs, you will need to include

```
options.LoginProviders.Remove(typeof(AzureActiveDirectoryLoginProvider));
options.LoginProviders.Add(typeof(AzureActiveDirectoryExtendedLoginProvider));
```

This allows the runtime to use the server flow in addition to the client flow (leveraging the Active Directory Authentication Library) which was first released with the .NET backend.

Pending that, or in the case of the Node runtime, the next thing to do is check the AAD configuration. In the AAD portal, make sure that your application registration uses your mobile service's /login/aad endpoint for the resource URI. It must match exactly the value provided in the Mobile Services portal. This should also be one of the redirect URIs if you are using the Node backend. For .NET, you would use the /signin-aad endpoint for the redirect URI instead.

You should also check that you have copied the Client ID from the AAD registration and pasted it into the Mobile Services portal's Identity Tab. For completeness, the "Allowed Tenants" field should also be filled out, but I don't believe it is the cause of this issue.

Lastly, if your AAD tenant is federated with ADFS, then there is a wide range of issues that could lead to this. The biggest case comes from the WAB needing to be configured for Enterprise Authentication. This typically only causes problems when the device is domain joined / on the corporate network. That behavior is a known bug for the Mobile Services Windows Store SDK, but there is a workaround available. Glad to provide that if needed.

Comment: Very helpful Matt, adding the nuget package and the code tot he WebApiConfig.cs solved it first time.

Actually - nearly - I had the reply url in AD configured as https://<backend name>.azure-mobile.net/login/aad (lifed from the mobile services identity configuration) and I needed to change/add to https://<backend name>.azure-mobile.net/signin-aad (but the error message from AD was clear and helpful)

Comment: Super solution. It helped me a lot. I was scratching my head for many hours for this solution.